# How to differentiate between adjacent boxes of same size and color in vpython

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphics, 3d, vpython

I have a code to place boxes of similar size and color, adjacent to each other in Vpython. However on rendering them, they look seamless(like one bigger box). Is there any way to add borders or any other way i can disgustingly render these boxes? Appreciate any hints. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might place a very thin black box between the two boxes. You could also use the curve object to decorate the boxes.

I'll advertise that a better place to pose VPython questions is in the VPython forum at

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users